# Calculating (qty * rate = amount) but it is changeable by inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, dom

I want to do a calculation on
`eqty * rate = amount`
`amount - discount + taxes = bill amount`
`bill amount + round off = net amount`

I know it can be done easily, but the problem is that any one can change the value   through inspect element. To stop that I have to recalculate the values again in server side and this will make the work duplicate and increase the chances of error from developer side.

please suggest me the right way

Comment: do it serverside directly then.

Comment: any suggestion to way out of this will be highly appreciable.

Comment: we are using MVC, in that case we have to hold previous value on server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot stop anyone changing your client-side code, or HTML, by using the DOM inspector. For this reason you should ***always*** verify any values on the server side. Any client side business logic should be considered as a pure courtesy to the user, and it should not be relied upon.

Comment: you mean we have to write the code twice client side \ server side and there is no option to stop this duplicacy

Comment: There is if you always use the server to calculate the amount by using AJAX. Other than that, no. Client side and server side are separate entities.

Comment: Makes no odds - the problem and solution are the same.

Comment: if we opt server side calculation via ajax then in that case we have to hold previous values too. is there any way to do so.

Comment: You've not described your logic, but there's lots of ways. TempData, session, cookies, localstorage, sessionstorage, database. I would suggest googling to find the one which suits your needs best.